# React.js state date become correct after second ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I purposely send response with an error, to check that everything is OK, but the first request I get success response(but it's failure) and only after a second I received error. It seems that the state is not updated or does not have time to update after firs call.

Question: Why in the first ajax request I do not get failure case

**Update**

I add code, but nothing to change. Also I remove code from save function

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.product.id != nextProps.product.id) {
        this.setState({product: Object.assign({}, nextProps.product)});
    }

    if(this.state.saving) {
        if(this.props.errorMessage) {
            toastr.error(this.props.errorMessage)
        } else {
            toastr.success('Product saved');
        }

        this.setState({saving: false});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax call is asynchronous, but you're evaluating the `errorMessage` property immediately after firing off the ajax request. The first time you make the ajax request, your `errorMessage` property will be undefined, so you'll immediately move to the `else` case, calling `toastr.success('Product saved');`

Meanwhile, the ajax request will fail, updating the `errorMessage` property. Upon sending a second ajax request, the code will again immediately evaluate the `errorMessage` property, but this time it will contain the error returned by the first request, and will call `toastr.error(this.props.errorMessage);`

Generally speaking, it's a good idea to use React.js in the way that it was intended. If you want to perform an action that updates something in `this.props`, you can listen for changes to the `props` object by overriding the `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` function. When you call `dispatch(something)` your component will receive an update. You can inspect `nextProps` to see if the `errorMessage` property has changed, and call your `toastr` methods from there.

For a detailed explanation, please see the documentation at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Thank you for answer, Graham. Yep, you absolutely right. But how i can wait for completing ajax call and after that go to next?

Comment: Depends on what your function `saveProduct(this.state.product)` returns, but you could refactor it to return a Promise. Have you used Promises before?

P.S., if you think this was the correct answer, then please upvote and accept :) I'll be happy to add further detail on how to solve your problem, but you may wish to edit your original question to include this follow-up question so others can benefit from understanding.

Comment: Alternatively, you could listen for the change to the `errorMessage` property by overriding the `componentWillReceiveProps()` function (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) - and call your `toastr` functions there.

Comment: I updated question. I wrote code, like you said, but still the same error

Comment: this.props.errorMessage still undefiend after first call, but reducer call correct.